# Better way to search nested arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

For context, I am trying to solve this problem.

- A dentist appointment schedule validation software
- Implement a superclass `Appointment` and sub classes `OneTime`, `Day` and `Month`. An `Appointment` has a `description` (for example, "Root Canal"), and `dates` information (you can use Date object or int Year, Int Month, Int Day). Fill an array of `Appointment` objects with a mixture of appointments.
- Write a method OccursOn inside each of the sub classes that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date (OneTime), day (Day) or month (Month). Ask the user to enter a date to check (for example, 2006 10 5), and ask to user if they want to check against `OneTime`, `Day` or `Month` appointment. Based on what the user selected, OccursOn inside each of the sub class should run and display any matching appointment and associated descriptions.

This is what I have so far.

```
class Appointment
   attr_accessor :day, :month, :year, :info
   def initialize(day, month, year, info)
     @day = day
     @month = month
     @year = year
     @info = info
   end

   def occursOn

   end
end

class OneTime < Appointment
  def OneTime.occursOn(day, month, year)
    if @day.to_i == day.to_i && @month.to_i == month.to_i && @year.to_i == year.to_i
      puts "Good"
    else
      puts "Not Good"
    end
  end
end

class Day < Appointment
  def Day.occursOn(day)
    if @day.to_i == day.to_i

      puts "Good"
    else
      puts "Not Good"
    end
  end
end

class Month < Appointment
  def Month.occursOn(month)
    if @month.to_i == month.to_i
      puts "Good"
    else
      puts "Not Good"
    end
  end
end

app1 = OneTime.new("10", "11", "2018","Root Canal")
app2 = Day.new("10", "11", "2018", "Root Canal")
app3 = Month.new("10", "11", "2018", "Root Canal")
app4 = OneTime.new("11", "11", "2018", "Cleaning")
app5 = Day.new("11", "11", "2018", "Cleaning")
app6 = Month.new("11", "11", "2018", "Cleaning")
a = Array.new
a << app1 << app2 << app3 << app4 << app5 << app5 << app6



puts "Please enter the day of the appointment that you would like to search for"
day = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the month of the appointment that you would like to search for"
month = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter the year of the appointment that you would like to search for"
year = gets.chomp


puts "Enter a number 1-3 to choose an answer out of OneTime, Day, or Month to search in that catagory respectivly"
answer = gets.chomp
if answer == "1"
  OneTime.occursOn(day, month, year)
elsif answer == "2"
  Day.occursOn(day)
elsif answer =="3"
  Month.occursOn(month)
else
  puts "Wrong answer"
end
```

I'm trying to verify that a user's input corresponding with 'day', 'month', and 'year' match the numbers in each of the array values that correspond to the method the user input. So 'OneTime.OccursOn' should only search arrays made with 'OneTime.new'. I can't use .include? because of the possibility of the same value day and month.

This looks useful, but I don't know how I would implement something like this with my sub-classes.

```
array = [
  ["A", "X"],
  ["B", "Y"],
  ["C", "Z"]
]


str = "Y"
arr = array.find{|a| a[1] == str}
puts arr[0] if arr
# => B
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your sample code does not work.  You can confirm it easily.  The reason is, in `class Day < Appointment` for example, the variable `a` is undefined.  As a result, `Day.OccursOn(day)` would raise NameError.  So, you had better update your question, and present the code that at least does not raise an exception.

Comment: Edited it to something similar to the answer you gave, the first post had if statements left over from when I was testing possible solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to achieve what you want (providing my interpretation of your intention is correct).  I use the method name `occursOn` (note in Ruby, the first character of a method name **should be a lower-case alphabet**).

```
class Day < Appointment
  def occursOn(day)
    if @day.to_i == day.to_i  # Compares as integers
      puts "Good"
    else
      puts "Not Good"
    end
  end
end
```

Then, a sample test:

```
app2 = Day.new("10", "11", "2018", "Root Canal")
app2.occursOn(10)   # => printing "Good"
app2.occursOn(999)  # => printing "not Good"
```

### Description

Use an instance method, as opposed to a class method like `def Day.occursOn(day)`.
In Ruby, when an (instance) method is called, the method of the name in the class of the instance has the highest priority, and therefore the methods of the same name in its parent or ancestor classes are ignored.

It is one of the core principles in Ruby.  I recommend you to read through the section of Classes in Ruby textbooks, for example, [Programming Ruby](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html) (free on-line).

Comment: If I were to use (instance) methods instead of class methods there is an "undefined method 'occursOn' for Day:Class". Fixed this by changing the Day.occursOn(day) to occursOn(day) only to have an "undefined method 'occursOn' for main:Object" This is all in the if else statements at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Run the code in my answer (definition of `Day`), after running the definition of your `class Appointment`, and run my 3-line sample test (included in the answer)! It succeeds.